# Extract part of a string in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, extract

In SQL Server 2008 R2 I need to extract from a string everything between the character 50 and 60. 
I've searched for a similar function on the internet but didn't really find something which can address the problem.

I can do it on Excel with a formula like: `MID(A2, 50, 10)`

Comment: SubString() - http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The sql function is called substring

```
  substring(fieldname,50,10)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need more flexibility, for instance if the separation does not occur in the same place each time you can use CHARINDEX. Here are a couple examples.

```
REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(fieldname),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(fieldname))))
```

If your string is "AA 1235 A9" the output will be A9.

```
REPLACE(STUFF(fieldname,1,CHARINDEX('- ',fieldname),''),REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(fieldname),CHARINDEX(' ',REVERSE(fieldname)))),'')
```

Adding on to the first bit of code you can also pull the middle portion which will result in 1235. The ' ' is flexible and if there is a hyphen, asterisk or some other symbol/identifier you need to use then just use that instead of the space.